# Ubī ūtar verbō "queō" prō "possum"?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

The word *queō* (*"I am able"*) is back-formed from *nequeō* (*"I am not able"*) and, to the best of my knowledge, is equivalent in meaning to *possum*.

When would one use *queō* over *possum*, or vice versa?

Comment: *Queo* is especially common after negation. *Nihil facere quit* 'he can do nothing' vs. *omnia facere potest* 'he can do everything' (although both *nihil facere potest* and *omnia facere quit* are possible, even if the latter is rare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to establish an exact translation, but I believe that *possum* is something closer to "I can", rather them "I`m able to". Considering other romance languages that have a translation of "I can" as: posso (italian), posso (portuguese), je peux (french) and puedo (spanish); the similarity is clear. About its use, is just like in English.